# How to install libguestfs / guestfish for xen on CentOS 5.5?

Tags: centos, xen, yum, centos5

According to this page:
http://libguestfs.org/

I should be able to just type:

```
yum install '*guestf*'
```

However this returns back:

```
No package *guestf* available.
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install EPEL:

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#howtouse

Then note the version in EPEL 5 is very old, and multilib causes problems, so use:

```
yum --exclude='*.i[3456]86' install '*guestf*'
```

Comment: aha yeah, oops!